# ¿Cómo se crea una clase si uno de los tipo de dato de sus atributos depende de otra clase?

Tags: sql, clase

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso quisiera crear la clase Pedido, pero el tipo de dato de su atributo ubicación depende de la clase localización.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Arregle tu pregunta, pero... ese dibujo no nos dice nada, y tampoco se entiende bien tu problema...